# Connected to a wired network, but internet doesn't work

Tags: wired-networking, wired, ubuntu-17.04

Wired network shows connected, but internet doesn't work. Iam using **Ubuntu 17.04**

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

shows following in terminal :

```
description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 07
   serial: fc:45:96:84:73:b8
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:124 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a3200000-a3200fff memory:a3000000-a3003fff
```

I also tried by disabling secure boot, but it doesn't work too.

on `ifconfig` it shows :

```
enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether fc:45:96:84:73:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 104  bytes 12418 (12.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 978  bytes 75957 (75.9 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 405  bytes 44664 (44.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 405  bytes 44664 (44.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::e187:9d1f:f675:9bea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 98:54:1b:f3:33:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5568  bytes 3045587 (3.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4345  bytes 938706 (938.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note:) I have read most of similar threads/questions here before asking this. None of those works for me

Please help me resolve this issue.

PS:) if you think its a possible duplicate then please resolve my issue before closing this question (or) marking duplicate

Comment: If it's a dupe it should be flagged as such and that's it. A dupe should contain an answer that is entirely applicable, no point in repeating it. That said, please check whether or not you can ping 8.8.8.8 and `www.google.com`. If the former works but not the latter you have a DNS issue, just replace whatever DNS server for the Google's 8.8.8.8.

Comment: There is no assigned ip in the `lshw` output, nor for `enp1s0:` - e.g. I have `ip=192.168... latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s`, and `inet addr:192.168... ` (ifconfig). So looks like either a DHCP problem, or no assigned manual IP.

Comment: @MichaelBay on pinging it just shows pinging google or 8.8.8.8 with some bytes of data, but it never stops (or) goes beyond this.

Comment: @Hannu it used to work previously, so i didn't used to assign ip manually. suddenly after a system restart few days back, it stopped working

Comment: @mcjoshi Then check your DHCP server. The server doesn't or cannot provide an IP (broken cable?).

Comment: No i tried it in different ports and with different cables. still doesn't works... Fresh installation of ubuntu is the only solution in my mind.